# Python Requests.Json() Incorrect Decoding

Tags: python

I am trying to get and decode JSON data from [Roblox's API](https://groups.roblox.com/docs#!/Groups/get_v1_groups_groupId). If I type the link it generates into my search engine, the JSON data it returns is:

```
{
"id": 1,
"name": "RobloHunks",
"description": "",
"owner": {
    "buildersClubMembershipType": "None",
    "userId": 1179762,
    "username": "RobloTim",
    "displayName": "RobloTim"
},
"shout": {
    "body": "...",
    "poster": {
        "buildersClubMembershipType": "None",
        "userId": 1179762,
        "username": "RobloTim",
        "displayName": "RobloTim"
    },
    "created": "2020-07-08T12:17:33.607Z",
    "updated": "2020-09-09T06:24:12.66Z"
},
"memberCount": 164000,
"isBuildersClubOnly": false,
"publicEntryAllowed": true
}
```

If, however, I try to decode it in python I get this:

```
{
"id": 1,
"name": "RobloHunks",
"description": "",
"owner": {
    "buildersClubMembershipType": "None",
    "userId": 1179762,
    "username": "RobloTim",
    "displayName": "RobloTim"
},
"shout": None,
"memberCount": 164000,
"isBuildersClubOnly": False,
"publicEntryAllowed": True
}
```

The segment of my python code handling this is:

```
data = requests.get('https://groups.roblox.com/v1/groups/1').json()
time.sleep(5)
body = data['shout']['body']
username = data['shout']['poster']['username']
```

I tried this with another Roblox GroupId (changing 'https://groups.roblox.com/v1/groups/1' to 'https://groups.roblox.com/v1/groups/2') and it worked as intended. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you mean by "type the link it generates into my search engine"?  The Python output you show is exactly the same as what I get in a browser, if you're getting any more data via another method I'd have to assume that the URL is somehow different.

Comment: Maybe it was there before, but now, in the json the url returns, "shout" is `null`.

Comment: I don’t think the variable factor/flakiness is requests.json() decoding, it’s what the website is returning. Prove it by a) tracing the messages flowing to/from your app using e.g. Telerik Fiddler, and b) logging the raw received data to file as well as what you say is the erroneously decoded data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Roblox group had in their settings to not allow non-members to view shout. Fixed by updating that setting.